# Safely run arbitrary commands in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, sandbox

I would like the user to specify a list of commands for gathering statistics about the system that he/she is interested in.  I would run these under various scenarios automatically.  However I'm not quite sure how to sandbox the commands safely.

One option would be to carry a whitelist of allowed commands, but it would need to be maintained.  I'd like to be really flexible such as, is it possible to run an arbitrary command in Linux with read only file permissions?

What are your ideas?

Comment: You could have a user who owns no files and can't sudo, I suppose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Gentoo there is the `sandbox` tool that allows running programs in a sandbox with only read access to the outside. I built it successfully under Ubuntu, too. The sources can be downloaded [here](http://dev.gentoo.org/~vapier/dist/sandbox-2.2.tar.lzma).

Comment: This looks very useful.  Now if only they had some documentation.

Comment: @kalaxy: `sandbox` is used in Gentoo to safely run `make install` when building packages, so a lot of the documentation you'll find will be on that. This http://bugday.gentoo.org/sandbox.html seems useful. Tweaking more (e.g. adding selective r+w support http://devmanual.gentoo.org/function-reference/sandbox-functions/index.html) would require you to install additional Gentoo software from `portage`, e.g. `ebuild.sh` and deps from http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/portage/main/branches/2.1.7/bin/?pathrev=15576

Answer (score 2):

SELinux will allow you to do this. You can either put the executables into a restricted domain, or you can create a new role with limited permissions.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, unfortunately we aren't running SELinux.